# Symlink for libxml2 not working after installing and configuring

Tags: php, symfony, rhel

I am currently have two PHP version in my server ;

> **PHP version 5.2.11** - the current version of the php in the server
>   wherein many programs uses it. Have `libxml2-2.6.16`  as libxml2 version.

Virtually Installed PHP

> **PHP version 5.4.44** - the virtually installed version of php in the server. Since, I upload my project in the server which uses **Symfony
>   Framework**. As symfony requirement, php version must be at least have
>   a php version of 5.3. And so, we installed this PHP version virtually.

After setting all the necessary  configuration, we run it in the browser using its customize port. Unfortunately,the page gives this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message '[ERROR 3070] CT 'container': The content model is not determinist. (in file:////home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd - line 20, column 0)' in /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:96 Stack trace: #0 /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(218): Symfony\Component\Config\Util\XmlUtils::loadFile('/home/sanchez/...', Array) #1 /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(41): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToDOM('/home/sanchez/...') #2 /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php(48): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLo in /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 220
```

To understand more about the error, I research in the internet and find some related topics that may help. Then,, I found out that it is all about the **libxml2**, so I installed another libxml2 version in my directory (personal) and just use symlink for it to point to my directory. By the way I install, **libxml2-2.8.0** as libxml2 version. I am also using **RHEL4**.After setting again the neccessary configuration , it still give the same error as above.

How can I solve this? Is it really possible to have two libxml2 version on the server? Do I miss any configuration or something? Is my libxml2 version and php version 5.4.44 is compatible? Or there is any libxml2 that is compatible with my php version? What should I do?

Appreciate any help.Thanks.

Comment: when I try to make a file that have `php_info()` inside, it gives me the php version 5.4.44 but the **libxml2**, it still uses the `2.6.16` version. How can I fix this?